# Multism11 differential amplification circuit

Tags: multisim, differential-amplifier

When I tried to draw a differential amplification circuit based on a sample picture and connected it to an oscilloscope, I'm getting a flatline on Channel A with a value of 0. What could be the possible issue?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you apply the same voltage on the two inputs? It is a "common" mode input, not "differential".

Comment: What is Multism?

Answer (score 3):

Seems that your scale is 10 MV/Div change it to 10 mV/Div